# What does it mean to be a continuous function between Banach spaces?

Tags: continuity, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $f:X→Y$ a continuous mapping.

What does it mean that $f$ is continuous between normed spaces? I only can find continuity considering metric spaces. Would it be correct to state the following:

$f$ is continuous at $x \in X$ if and only if

$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \ \exists \delta>0 \ \forall x_0 \in X :\|x-x_0\|_X< \delta \Rightarrow \|f(x)-f(x_0)\|_Y< \varepsilon. $$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta>0,\forall x_0 \in X, \|x-x_0\|_X< \delta \Rightarrow \|f(x)-f(x_0)\|_Y< \varepsilon. $

Comment: Every normed space is a metric space.

Comment: Thank you @Bob, I corrected it.

Comment: @azif00 so it fine to just use this normed based definition for continuity?

Comment: You need to put $\forall x$ in there.  And if $f$ is also **linear**, then it is enough to do $\exists \delta > 0,\;\forall x \in X,\;\|x\|<\delta \Rightarrow \|f(x)\|<1$.

Comment: @GEdgar You mean to get that the whole function is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every normed space $X$ is a metric space $(X,d)$, with the metric $d$ **induced** by the norm in the following way:
$$d(x,y) = \|x-y\| \quad\quad \forall \, x,y\in X$$
With that in mind, you can use the notion of continuity for maps between metric spaces.